# How Postgres negotiate TLS usage?

Tags: postgresql

I am puzzled a bit about Postgres option sslmode=prefer. It implies that it negotiates with the server to figure out whether the server supports TLS or not.

I am curious how it's done. Does it try TLS first and if it fails, try without TLS or am I missing something in TLS (or Postgres) which allow them to truly negotiate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it try TLS first and if it fails, try without TLS

Yes.  And when both attempts fail, this might be visible, as two different error messages might be produced.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional info on top of @janes answer:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html

> To initiate an SSL-encrypted connection, the frontend initially sends
> an SSLRequest message rather than a StartupMessage. The server then
> responds with a single byte containing S or N, indicating that it is
> willing or unwilling to perform SSL, respectively. The frontend might
> close the connection at this point if it is dissatisfied with the
> response. To continue after S, perform an SSL startup handshake (not
> described here, part of the SSL specification) with the server. If
> this is successful, continue with sending the usual StartupMessage. In
> this case the StartupMessage and all subsequent data will be
> SSL-encrypted. To continue after N, send the usual StartupMessage and
> proceed without encryption.